# Android - How can I change the color of a part of a String located in string.xml?

Tags: android, string, kotlin, colors, textview

In my application (in Kotlin), I have a string like this in my string.xml : `<string name="buy_price">Buy %1$s %2$s for %3$s %4$s</string>`

Where, for example %1$s is the amount, %2$s the item name, %3$s the amount and %4$s the fiat's name.

I want to set some colors for %1$s, %2$s, %3$s, ... . But I dont know how. I have been thinking to concatenate like 5 textView which store one part of the string but it's not very clean ...

Can you help me please

Comment: Try to research Spannable class. Maybe it can helps you

Comment: I already tried Spannable class but not working with strings located in string.xml

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**Spannable implementation:**

```
val category = "Monitor"
val item = "LG - 2562"
val currency = "Rs"
val amount = "1234"

val text = getString(R.string.buy_price, category, item, currency, amount)

val categoryColor = Color.BLUE
val categoryStart = text.indexOf(category)
val categoryEnd = categoryStart + category.length

val itemColor = Color.GREEN
val itemStart = text.indexOf(item)
val itemEnd = itemStart + item.length

val currencyColor = Color.RED
val currencyStart = text.indexOf(currency)
val currencyEnd = currencyStart + currency.length

val amountColor = Color.MAGENTA
val amountStart = text.indexOf(amount)
val amountEnd = amountStart + amount.length

textView.text = SpannableStringBuilder(text).apply {
    setSpan(
        ForegroundColorSpan(categoryColor),
        categoryStart,
        categoryEnd,
        Spannable.SPAN_EXCLUSIVE_EXCLUSIVE
    )
    setSpan(
        ForegroundColorSpan(itemColor),
        itemStart,
        itemEnd,
        Spannable.SPAN_EXCLUSIVE_EXCLUSIVE
    )
    setSpan(
        ForegroundColorSpan(currencyColor),
        currencyStart,
        currencyEnd,
        Spannable.SPAN_EXCLUSIVE_EXCLUSIVE
    )
    setSpan(
        ForegroundColorSpan(amountColor),
        amountStart,
        amountEnd,
        Spannable.SPAN_EXCLUSIVE_EXCLUSIVE
    )
}
```

**Result:**

[image]

Answer (score 2):

You can try with [Html.fromHtml](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/text/Html#fromHtml(java.lang.String,%20int))

I believe you can put on strings.xml something like:

```
<string name="buy_price">Buy &lt;span style='color:blue'>%1$s&lt;/span> &lt;span style='color:red'>%2$s&lt;/span> for &lt;span style='color:green'>%3$s&lt;/span> &lt;span style='color:yellow'>%4$s&lt;/span></string>
```

Then you call `textView.text = Html.fromHtml(getString(R.string.buy_price), 0)`

Obs: in strings.xml I replace `<` with `&lt;`. It's a workaround because I believe getString will try to parse html tags like `<b>` or `<u>`.

Comment: Good shout on the ``&lt;`` thing!

Comment: Thanks for ur answer. Tried with span and font but didn't work. The color didn't change.

Answer (score 1):

Luiz's answer works (so I don't want the credit!) but just for anyone looking into this in general...

You can do this by wrapping your string's text in HTML tags to style it. There's two ways to display it:

- set it to a text attribute in XML
- set it in code using `Html.fromHtml(getString(R.string.whatever))`

---

Two tags you can use:

- `<font color="#FF0000"></font>` - works in code and XML
- `<span style="color:#FF0000"></span>` - works in code, not XML, possibly allows more styling. Don't add spaces in the style bit!

---

As Luiz says, you need to replace `<` characters with `&lt;` so `getString` doesn't mess up the tags before `fromHtml` can get to them (it does say it returns the text "stripped of styling information"). However!

- `<` - broken by `getString`, works in XML
- `&lt;` - works in code, breaks (not parsed as a tag) in XML

---

So basically:

- using the string in code? Use `<font>` tags *or* `style` attributes, and change the opening `<` of tags to `&lt;`
- using the string in XML? Use the `<font>` tag and leave the opening `<` alone
- using the string in code **and** XML? You probably need two versions to handle the different opening tag characters!
- using positional arguments? You're doing it in code

I haven't used data binding so I can't say for sure, but I'd assume that since you're running code (that's just defined in the XML) all the same caveats apply as running code in general.